# How can I find partially-matching values in an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, observablecollection

I want to search through my `ObservableCollection` for any matches I can find for a specific item. In this case, my item is "artist". Basically it's just a search bar where the user can type an artist name.

I did this and it works, but the user has to put the exact same value:

```
   //user type "david guetta"
   if (myCollection.Any(x => x.artist== input.Value))
   {
       //...
   }
```

How can I find partial matches in my collection, where the user can type "david" and retrieve all the artists containing this string?

I tried to use regex with an array of strings and that worked as well, but I can't manage to do the same with my collection.

```
string[] artists=
{
    "Malcom George",
    "Willis H. David",
    "David Bowie",
    "Davidson"
};

string pattern = input.Value;

foreach (string s in artists)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides being able to retrieve results also when some but not all the words of the item are provided (which can be done by something the lines Matteo suggests, in his answer), you may be interested in considering one of the nuget [Fuzzy logic] packages (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DuoVia.FuzzyStrings/) to enable your app to return results when only an approximation of the real data is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that in your `Any`'s predicate, instead of equality comparison, just check if the `string` contains the input `string`.

You can do like this:

```
myCollection.Any(x => x.artist.Contains(input.Value))
```

If you need case insensitive search you can do the following:

```
myCollection.Any(x => x.artist.IndexOf(input.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

To get the objects, you can use Where method instead of Any

```
myCollection.Where(x => x.artist.Contains(input.Value))

myCollection.Where(x => x.artist.IndexOf(input.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

Comment: Your solution works fine, but how can i retrieve the entire object when i get a match ? i have others items such as title, year ...

Comment: @ozer you mean that you want to check every member(title, year...) against the input string?

Comment: Yes the input string would be my index to get the entire object when i get a match

Comment: @ozer Then you'll need to add `or` conditions in the predicate and check the fields there. Like: `x => x.artist.Contains(input.Value) || x => x.title.Contains(input.Value)` etc...

Comment: I see but its not really what i want. Now that i get the match, i would like to get the index of that match so that i can navigate through my obsevablecollection and get the entire object

Comment: @ozer Ok, if I understood correctly, you can use `Where` method instead of `Any`. Where will return the objects that matches the condition, `Any` just return true/false